# I 'm not getting ng-message on validation

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a form on AngularJS, I'm using required attribute on username,
it's not working on submitting the form.

```
<div ng-app="myOwnModule" ng-controller="myOwnCon">
  <form name="myOwnForm" novalidate >
    <input type="text" name="moname" id="moname" ng-model="myOwnForm.moname" required />
    <div ng-messages="myOwnForm.moname.$error" ng-if="myOwnForm.moname.$touched">
      <p ng-message="myOwnForm.moname.$error.required">Required</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="mosave" id="mosave" ng-click="send($event)" value="Send" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**My module**

```
var myOwnModule = angular.module('myOwnModule', ['ngMessages']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have conflict with you data `model` which you have used for binding and the form name. Because as I can see you are `myOwnForm` for data & `myOwnForm` for form name. You should change your data model to use some different `name` like `model`

And other than that don't use `ng-show`.

```
<form name="myOwnForm" novalidate >
    <input type="text" name="moname" id="moname" ng-model="model.test" required />
    <div ng-messages="myOwnForm.moname.$error" ng-show="myOwnForm.moname.$touched">
      <p ng-message="required">Required</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="mosave" id="mosave" ng-click="send($event)" value="Send" />
</form>
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/s8N1LtjfFaNtL0Hmh3Rs?p=preview)

Comment: @sridhar I doubt that is because of `ng-if`

Comment: I have changed to `myform.moname` but that too not working, bro.
And one more thing to add, My controller is running on submitting, after that only the ordinary html required attr is working.
but my ng-message is not working

Comment: @sridhar do check plunkr please

Comment: hai bro, I'm doubting that "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ilinktask-585a8de2492f39.sharepoint.com/sites/ilinktraining/trainin…ask-585a8de2492f39.sharepoint.com%2fsites%2filinktraining%2ftraining_ilink' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." is it,the reason for my problem  ? I got this in my console. thanks

Comment: Yes that is the reason..Seems like angular file is on secure environment.. Do change its protocol to http